# Proof that the elements of a set are subsets of its union.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am currently self-studying some set theory (as a highschool student) from Herbert's elements of set theory. One of the exercises is to show that every member of a set $A$ is a subset of $\bigcup{A}$. My attempt;

Let $A$ be a set. Then;

$\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)=\{x:x\subseteq\bigcup A\}\\\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space=\{x:\forall a(a \in x \implies a\in\bigcup A)\} = \{x:(\forall a\in x)\ a\in\bigcup A\}$

Now define B;

$B=\{x\in\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A):x\in A\}\\ \ \ \ =\{x\in A:x\in\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)\}\\ \ \ \ =\{x\in A: (\forall a\in x)\ a\in\bigcup A\}$

Since $\bigcup A = \{a: (\exists x\in A)\ a\in x\}=\{a: \exists x(x\in A \implies a\in x)\}$;

$B=\{x \in A:(\forall a\in x)(\exists x\in A)\ a\in x\}=A$

Clearly,

$B\subset \mathcal{P}(\bigcup A) \  \therefore A\subset \mathcal{P}(\bigcup A) \ \therefore \ $ Every element of $A$ is a subset of $\bigcup A$. $\ \square$

So is my proof and usage of notation correct? Is there a better proof? Thanks.

Comment: Just a remark (your question has nicely been answered). Another way to denote $\bigcup A$ is $\bigcup_{a\in A}a$ or - if $A=\{a_i|i\in I\}$ - $\bigcup_{i\in I}a_i$. Often persons are more familiar with those notations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof seems correct to a quick scan. However the proof can be written much more simply. The definition of the subset relation $\subseteq$ is:
$$
X\subseteq Y \quad\text{means}\quad z\in X \implies z\in Y.
$$
So if we want to prove "every element of $A$ is a subset of $\cup A$", the most straightforward conversion of the structure-of-the-statement-to-be-proved to proof-structure would be this:

- Let $\alpha$ be any element of $A$. We want to prove that $\alpha$ is a subset of $\cup A$.
- Thus let $a$ be any element of $\alpha$. We need to prove that $a\in \cup A$.
- (and then prove $a\in \cup A$ using the definition $\cup X = \{ z\colon (\exists W\in X)\ z\in W\}$)

Comment: So is the following proof correct?

Let $\alpha \in A$. Then we aim to show that $\alpha \subseteq \bigcup A$;

Let $a\in \alpha$. Note that; 

$\bigcup A = \{x: (\exists b \in A) \ x\in b \}$

Since $\alpha \in A$, and $a \in \alpha$, it follows that $a\in \bigcup A$. 

Hence, $\forall \alpha (\alpha \in A \implies \alpha \subseteq \bigcup A)$.

Comment: Proof looks good :)